# Force Execution Result IN SSIS

Tags: ssis

Can some one  explain me what is use of **Force execution Results in ssis Package** Properties.I have not used this property even once.

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Have you looked it up in MSDN even once?

Answer (score 4):

It's mostly used to ***fake*** the results of a task or container and tell SSIS / the execution engine / caller what the status is, instead of the actual status of a task or container execution.

See [Faking success in SSIS](http://dougbert.com/blog/post/Faking-success-in-SSIS.aspx) for a clear detailed explanation.

Also from **SQL Server Books On Line**.

> You can use the `ForceExecutionResult` property on a task or container
>   to test the use of checkpoints in a package. By setting
>   ForceExecutionResult of the task or container to Failure, you can
>   imitate real-time failure. When you rerun the package, failed tasks
>   and containers will be rerun.

Comment: Hello Shiva, Thank you for the info.Can you tell me a real time example where we will use it?