# SSIS and reporting success after for loop retry

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Given the For Loop retry scheme below (working), how can I make the package return success versus failure? I've seen some tantalizing clues such as a task or package's ForceExecutionResult = Success but not sure how I can incorporate that into my process (I have many just like the below). If indeed setting ForceExecutionResult is an answer, do I set this using a ScriptTask or Expression? Is that property available in an obvious way, other than from the properties page? Thank you.

[image: For Loop Retry]

Additional note/explanation: I need to conditionally return success or failure based on the number of retries. A failure, retry, and success is success. In my For Loop, three retries is a failure. I can't arbitrarily set ForceExecutionResults = Success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force Execution Result IN SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896420/force-execution-result-in-ssis)

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi I am aware of the property, I mentioned it in my posted question. I need to access that property in my For Loop so that I can set that property appropriately on a retry success.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution or at least one approach was to assign the On Error Handler's variable Propagate to True or False, using the User variables I was already using for the For Loop try scheme.

```
@[System::Propagate] = @[User::CountryIncrement]  == @[User::RetryCount] - 1
```

You put that (above) in an Expression Task in the Task's On Error event handler. That way when the error retry count has been reached, the error will propagate up to the parent and correctly report failure. If it retried once, say, and subsequently succeeded, Propagate will be False and not bubble up. The Tasks Job Step will report success.